# Best ways to split a string with matching curly braces

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm working in C# right now and I'm using JSON.Net to parse json strings to well, C# objects.  Part of my problem is that I'm getting some strings like this:

```
{"name": "John"}{"name": "Joe"}
```

When I try to deserialize with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>`, it throws an exception.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to split of this bigger string into smaller json strings.

I was thinking about going through the string and matching curly braces of "level 0".  Does this seem like a good idea?  Or is there some better method to do this?

Comment: where do you get this json from?

Comment: They are some test cases given to me from an exercise I was working on.

Comment: It's not valid Json but it can be with small changes [{"name": "John"},{"name": "Joe"}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `JsonTextReader` with the `SupportMultipleContent` flag set to true to read this non-standard JSON.  Assuming you have a class `Person` that looks like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize the JSON objects like this:

```
string json = @"{""name"": ""John""}{""name"": ""Joe""}";

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(json))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            Person p = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1lTU2v

Answer (score 2):

I found the best way is to convert your string to an array structure:

```
string json = "{\"name\": \"John\"}{\"name\": \"Joe\"}";

json = json.Insert(json.Length, "]").Insert(0, "[").Replace("}{", "},{");

// json now is     [{"name": "John"},{"name": "Joe"}] 
List<Person> result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

Assuming your class name is `Person` :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Well, the sample I provided was for when there was one level of curly braces.  Would this work if there are two or three levels?

Comment: @Benjamin post the most complex example that you can get, and I'll be more than happy to give it a try :)