# how can i fixed invalid json and Deserialize in list<> using json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

when i try to deploy json then an error occur :

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: [. Path '', line 1, position 37.
```

when i do lot of search in google i got that json is invalid because its have `multiple roots` 
json is:

```
{"slotId":"1","slotName":"9:00 am"}{"slotId":"3","slotName":"9:15 am"}{"slotId":"4","slotName":"9:15 am"}{"slotId":"6","slotName":"9:30 am"}{"slotId":"7","slotName":"9:30 am"}{"slotId":"8","slotName":"9:45 am"}{"slotId":"9","slotName":"9:45 am"}{"slotId":"10","slotName":"10:00 am"}{"slotId":"11","slotName":"10:15 am"}{"slotId":"12","slotName":"10:30 am"}
```

i am tryin to Deserialize  in list<>:

```
                mSlotType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SlotType>>(json);
            mAdapter = new SlotTimeAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.MrngTimeSlot_ListView_Rowlayout, mSlotType);
```

json class is:

```
 class SlotType
{
    public string slotId { get; set; }
    public string slotName { get; set; } 

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<SlotType> slottype { get; set; }
    }
}
```

please help me

php code for develop json is :

```
$Details = array();
    $detail = array("slotId" => $row['slotId'],
                        "slotName" => $row['slotName'],
                            );
        array_push($Details, $detail);

    echo json_encode($Details );
```

when i try to check my json on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it gve me an output :

```
`[{
  "slotId":"1",
  "slotName":"9:00 am"}][{
  "slotId":"3",
  "slotName":"9:15 am"}][{
  "slotId":"4",
  "slotName":"9:15 am"}][{
  "slotId":"6",
  "slotName":"9:30 am"}][{
  "slotId":"7",
  "slotName":"9:30 am"}][{
  "slotId":"8",
  "slotName":"9:45 am"}][{
  "slotId":"9",
  "slotName":"9:45 am"}][{
  "slotId":"10",
  "slotName":"10:00 am"}][{
  "slotId":"11",
  "slotName":"10:15 am"}][{
  "slotId":"12",
  "slotName":"10:30 am"}]`
```

please help me as i am not able to understand where the problem is

Comment: try to wrap your raw json with [] and delimit each {} item by ,

Comment: Assuming you can't change the JSON (which isn't strictly valid), see [What is the correct way to use JSON.NET to parse stream of JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601594) or [Best ways to split a string with matching curly brances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429059/best-ways-to-split-a-string-with-matching-curly-brances/38429174#38429174).

Comment: json is not correct .when i check it on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it give me this list of error:

Comment: error:Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 12]
Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 23]
Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 34]
Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 45]
Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 56]
Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 67]
Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 78]
Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 89]
Error:Multiple JSON root elements[Code 22, Structure 100]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your JSON is malformed It should probably look like this:

```
{
    slottype: [{"slotId":"1","slotName":"9:00 am"},
    {"slotId":"3","slotName":"9:15 am"},
    {"slotId":"4","slotName":"9:15 am"},
    {"slotId":"6","slotName":"9:30 am"},
    {"slotId":"7","slotName":"9:30 am"},
    {"slotId":"8","slotName":"9:45 am"},
    {"slotId":"9","slotName":"9:45 am"},
    {"slotId":"10","slotName":"10:00 am"},
    {"slotId":"11","slotName":"10:15 am"},
    {"slotId":"12","slotName":"10:30 am"}]
}
```

- Square brackets denote a list type
- commas are required between list elements
- You will need the root element structure to match your root object better

Comment: what change i required in my code to get this json.

Comment: Compare, an extra pair of curly and square brackets to make it List and valid Json object

Comment: Huh the json here is valid

Comment: sorry but i am not able to understand.