# Error while deserializing json string into collection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, json.net

I have json string like below

`"{\"Key\":3296,\"Value1\":\"Test1\",\"Value2\":\"City\",\"Value3\":\"TX\",\"Value4\":null,\"Value5\":null,\"Value6\":null}{\"Key\":3297,\"Value1\":\"Test2\",\"Value2\":\"PUD\",\"Value3\":\"TX\",\"Value4\":null,\"Value5\":null,\"Value6\":null}"`

and corresponding C# class

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public string Value4 { get; set; }
    public string Value5 { get; set; }
    public string Value6 { get; set; }
}
```

> when i try to deserialize this string using Newtonsoft i get error
>
> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g.
>   {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyObject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'Key', line 1, position
>   7."}

I know that the string is not well formatted for json array. This is how i m getting the string and i dont have control over it.

What would be a best option here to convet that string into `IEnumerable` of MyObject. The string can have one object also.

Comment: Your JSON string is not valid as it consists of two separate objects just sitting next to each other, like `{object1}{object2}`.  You should put those into an array so it becomes `[{object1}, {object2}]`

Comment: as i said, i understand its not well formed. But that is how i receiving it

Comment: Well, if the string is always a list of simple objects (with no nesting) you can probably replace all instances of `}<whitespace?>{` with `},{`, wrap it in square brackets and you have a valid JSON string which you can deserialize w Newtonsoft.  If the string contains any curly braces within quotes, or nesting, you have a much more difficult task, and I would suggest having the folks who send you the string *fix it to be valid JSON* (which IMO should be your first approach).

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [What is the correct way to use JSON.NET to parse stream of JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26601594) or  [Best ways to split a string with matching curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429174/3744182) or [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063/3744182) or [Parsing large json file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32227436/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

Per James's answer (I'm sure you have figured this out but here it is). This should work with only 1 object as well:

```
string json = <your string here>;
json = "[" + json;
json = json.Replace("}{", "},{");
json += "]";
```

Not sure off-hand if there's a built-in way to do this in json.net.